# program to test all possibilities in a list

Tags: python

I'd first like to start that I am beginning my Python journey, so my code will certainly reflect that. I trying to write a program that will check if an entered number is a Kaprekar number by returning true or false. To do that, I've created the following functions:

`def list_to_num(list):` (returns a list as an int)

`def num_to_list(num):` (returns an int as a list)

Main program:

```
def is_kaprekar_number(num):
  
  square = num ** 2

  listeNum = num_to_list(square)

  x = 0
  p1 = listeNum[:x]
  p2 = listeNum[(x+1):]

  for i in range(len(listeNum)):
    if list_to_num(p1) + list_to_num(p2) == num:
      return 'True'
    else:
      return 'False'
  x += 1
    
print(is_kaprekar_number(9))
```

The output returns `False`

My main issue is that I am struggling test all possibilities in a list that was converted from the square of the number I am trying to test. i.e 45^2=2025

first iteration = 2 + 025 = 27, false - check next iteration

second iteration = 20 + 25 = 45, true, return `true`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The basic root if your problem is the ranges in the p1/p2 lines, which you would have learned if you had printed intermediate values.  Remember that the end point of a Python list is exclusive.  The range [0:0] contains nothing.  You need `p1 = listeNum[:x+1]` / `p2 = listeNum[x+1:]`.

Comment: And, as a side note, it is poor practice to name your variables after built-in Python types and functions.  In this case, that means `sum` and `list`.  And I assume you can see that `list_to_num` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts well noted! I suppose that I didn't see this as an issue since I translated my variables from my native language to English for this post but I can totally see why this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like that I can't format code in a comment.  Your loops were not properly nested; you were only splitting the list once, then checking that same string several times.  Plus, you can't return False until you've tried ALL the variations. Here is a version that works:

```
def is_kaprekar_number(num):
    square = num ** 2
    listeNum = num_to_list(square)

    for x in range(len(listeNum)):
        p1 = listeNum[:x+1]
        p2 = listeNum[x+1:]
        print(p1,p2)

        if list_to_num(p1) + list_to_num(p2) == num:
            return True
    return False
        
print(is_kaprekar_number(45))
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. That's for pointing out the nesting problem, that was beyond helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your question is why this is returning `False` even though 9<sup>2</sup> = 81 and 8 + 1 = 9 (helps to be explicit about these things).

First off, `p1,p2` are outside your loop, so those are computed once and never updated. Easy enough to fix - just move them into your loop body.

Second, a `return` statement terminates `is_kaprekar_number`, meaning there won't be any additional invocations of your loop after the first attempt. You want to terminate immediately if you find an appropriate split, but keep going if you don't, and only return `False` if you've exhausted all possible splits. Hence you need to remove the else condition and move `return False` outside the loop.

Thirdly, the upper bound on a python slic is not inclusive - `[0:x]` does not contain the `x`<sup>th</sup> element, so your slicing always excludes one digit.
I'll leave the explicit solution to you (or another answerer) to finish.

Finally, some general python idioms to make your life easier:

Want the first x elements of a list? `l[:x]`
Want the rest of the list? `l[x:]`

Need the digits of a non-negative integer? Convert to a string `str(i)`.
Finished slicing your string and need to go back to an integer? `int(s)`
(NB: You don't need to do that in this particular case, as you'd have  to modify the rest of the program logic to avoid trying to convert the empty string)

Using variable names like `list` that are already python types? `Don't do that!`

Don't use a counter in a `for` loop unless you have to, and don't loop over something you won't use.